# Beautiful soup pagination - only scrapes first page

Tags: beautifulsoup, pagination

I have one more issue with my BeautifulSoup scraper and was hoping you'd be able to help me. Since adding the code for it to extract information from the details pages, now the scraper only scrapes the first page and no longer scrapes the multiple pages outlined.

I assume it has to do with the loop but I'm not sure how to define this to ensure it doesn't cause issues.

Is there a better way for pagination?

I've posted the full code and bolded the new section that's causing problems.

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy
import requests
import csv
import time
import os
pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

with open(r'csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_print = csv.writer(f_output)

    file_is_empty = os.stat(r'C:\csv').st_size == 0
    if file_is_empty:
        csv_print.writerow(['Title', 'Company', 'Location', 'Salary', 'Summary', 'Link', 'Description', 'URL'])

    for page in pages:
        source = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=work+from+home&l=United+States&fromage=1&start={}'.format(page)).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

        results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "result"})

    for jobs in soup.find_all(class_='result'):

            try:
                title = jobs.h2.text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                title = None
            print('Title:', title)

            try:
                company = jobs.span.text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                company = None
            print('Company:', company)

            try:
                location = jobs.find('span', class_='location').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                location = None
            print('Location:', location)

            try:
                salary = jobs.find('span', class_='no-wrap').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                salary = None
            print('Salary:', salary)

            try:
                summary = soup.find('div', class_='summary').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                summary = None
            print('Summary:', summary)

            link = jobs.a['href']
            if 'http' not in link:
                link = ("https://www.indeed.com" + link)
            print('Link:', link)

            **page = requests.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            job_description = soup.find('div', id='jobDescriptionText').decode_contents(formatter="html")
            print('job_description:', job_description)
            try:
                url = soup.find('div', class_='icl-u-lg-hide').attrs['href']
            except Exception as e:
                url = None
            print('url:', url)**

            csv_print.writerow((title, company, location, salary, summary, link, job_description, url))

            print('--------')

            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Thank you so much :)
You guys are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things,

1. BeautifulSoup parse html, it has nothing to do with implementing the pagination process.
2. The way your code is written, it actually doesnt scrape the first page, it's scraping the last page. You have it iterating through the list of pages, and then have it parse the html (which in this case is the very last request made). you need to parse your `results` for each page. Meaning `for jobs in soup.find_all(class_='result'):` needs to be within your loop of `for page in pages:`
3. This is just my preference, but I like using `pandas`. So I used that instead of `csv` to write to file

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]


titleList = []
companyList = []
locList = []
salList = []
summaryList = []
linkList = []
descList = []
urlList = []


for page in pages:
    source = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=work+from+home&l=United+States&fromage=1&start={}'.format(page)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    print ('Page: %s' %page)

    results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "result"})

    for jobs in soup.find_all(class_='result'):

            try:
                title = jobs.h2.text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                title = None
            print('Title:', title)

            try:
                company = jobs.span.text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                company = None
            #print('Company:', company)

            try:
                location = jobs.find('span', class_='location').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                location = None
            #print('Location:', location)

            try:
                salary = jobs.find('span', class_='no-wrap').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                salary = None
            #print('Salary:', salary)

            try:
                summary = soup.find('div', class_='summary').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                summary = None
            #print('Summary:', summary)

            link = jobs.a['href']
            if 'http' not in link:
                link = ("https://www.indeed.com" + link)
            #print('Link:', link)

            page = requests.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            job_description = soup.find('div', id='jobDescriptionText').decode_contents(formatter="html")
            #print('job_description:', job_description)
            try:
                url = soup.find('div', class_='icl-u-lg-hide').attrs['href']
            except Exception as e:
                url = None
            #print('url:', url)

            titleList.append(title)
            companyList.append(company)
            locList.append(location)
            salList.append(salary)
            summaryList.append(summary)
            linkList.append(link)
            descList.append(job_description)
            urlList.append(url)


            print('--------')

            time.sleep(0.5)

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Title':titleList,
        'Company':companyList,
        'Location':locList, 
        'Salary':salList, 
        'Summary':summaryList, 
        'Link':linkList, 
        'Description':descList, 
        'URL':urlList})

df.to_csv('file.csv',index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.head(15).to_string())
                                                Title                        Company                                           Location             Salary                                            Summary                                               Link                                        Description   URL
0   Medical Transcription Documentation Specialist...                            new                                               None               None  Extract electronic medical record data includi...  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=b728723376dae...  Dane Street is looking for highly motivated ca...  None
1           Company Partnerships Data Contractor\nnew                            new        New York, NY 10001 (Flatiron District area)        $30 an hour                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=188b5c89acc25...  <div><div>Do you love gathering, analyzing and...  None
2   Customer Experience Associate - work from home...                            new  Baltimore, MD 21230 (Spring Garden Industrial ...  $16 - $17 an hour                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=bdf4e0b474852...  <div><div><div><b>About Hungry Harvest</b></di...  None
3   Customer Care Representative I - Houston, TX -...                            new                  Houston, TX 77036 (Bellaire area)               None                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=b144f9b3db19a...  <div><p><b>Description</b>\n</p>SHIFT: Day Job...  None
4                  Talent Acquisition Specialist\nnew                            new                                               None               None                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=f9c860e3dea80...  <p></p><div><p><b>The Position</b></p><p>\nTal...  None
5                  Talent Acquisition Specialist\nnew                            new                                               None               None                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=5b1609f84a81b...  <div><div><div><div>Job Details</div>\n</div><...  None
6                             Success Consultant\nnew                            new                                               None               None                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=e2b62a52550b8...  <div><div>WORK FROM HOME</div><div><h6 class="...  None
7   Work At Home Customer Service Specialist (Bell...                            new                                    Belle Glade, FL     $13.25 an hour                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=0bd3274a26a1f...  US55505\n<br/><br/>\nJob Description Details\n...  None
8                                 Data Associate\nnew                            new                                               None               None                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=88d65d8102b17...  <div></div><div><div><div><div>The DNC Coordin...  None
9                            States Data Analyst\nnew                            new                                               None               None                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8c84a472e6119...  <div></div><div><div><div><div>The DNC Coordin...  None
10                                              Coder              Franciscan Health                                               None               None  Understanding of payer relationships, requirem...  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=cc0748fa0c360...  <div><div>Ambulatory Coding | Franciscan Allia...  None
11                                     Data Associate  Democratic National Committee                                               None               None                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=88d65d8102b17...  <div></div><div><div><div><div>The DNC Coordin...  None
12  Work At Home Customer Service Specialist (Boyn...                            HSN                                  Boynton Beach, FL     $13.25 an hour                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=a59f7532662bc...  <p></p><div>US55505\n<p></p><p><b>Job Descript...  None
13                          Associate Project Manager                    ConvergeOne                                               None               None                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=cbc2520fc153b...  <div>C1 Company Overview:<div><b>\nConvergeOne...  None
14                      Customer Solutions Specialist        Webstaurant Store, Inc.                                         Albany, GA        $19 an hour                                               None  https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8f5bd656508fd...  <div><p>Customer Solutions Specialist</p>\n<p>...  None
....
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I've been looking for and struggling. Video tutorials only cover so much. 
Thank you kind stranger!